# Python: Subtract Minute off Time Variable in Filename within Try/Except Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, filenames, try-except

I'm trying to use Python to post a file dropped into a shared folder each night via API. All the posting code works -- the only thing I can't quite get is Python automatically grabbing the file name and uploading it to the SFTP.

The file's naming convention is: `fileYYMMDDHHMM.txt` (all two-digits) so if it generated last night at 10:10pm, it would be in as `file1606272210.txt`. If I could have Python automatically grab that file name, I'd then be able to submit it automatically. This is what I figured out already which is very close (and doesn't produce an error):

```
import datetime
import os.path, time
file = '/Users/Ryan/'    

def modification_date(folderfile):
    t = os.path.getmtime(folderfile)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
mdate = modification_date(file)
md = mdate.strftime("%y%m%d%H%M")
```

That returns something that would theoretically work by appending the time the folder was last modified, as that code would return something like `file1606272214.txt`. Though the problem is that our database automatically appends the minute timing based on when it creates the file, not when it hits my folder. So I'm usually about five minutes off, but it's never 100% consistent.

My initial thought was to attempt to write a loop that subtracts a minute off of my modification_date script until it actually finds the file -- but I don't think I'm good enough at `try/except` stuff yet to pull that off. And I'm also not sure if that's the best solution anyway -- open to whatever.

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you always going to be submitting the newest one? And is the first part of the filename consistent?

Comment: @Delioth       At least at this point, I can't ever imagine not. My database drops one file in a night and I'd like to post it every day. And first part of the file name is always just 'file'. (Can't edit how the database spits it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since your comment has cleared up that it'll be consistent and always newest, you can use some neat little tricks.

First, the `os` module has a command named `os.listdir(path)`- this will give you the filenames of files in the given directory ("/Users/Ryan" above). Since the start is consistent and the numbers are in descending order, you can just sort the list of names using the builtin `sorted()`. This will sort them such that the newest one (highest ordinal name, since numbers are predictable) will be last. You can `list.pop()` off the last one or just access it (`list[-1]`) and do what you will with it (move it and such).

If you have extra and/or static files in the same directory, you may need to filter things that start with your thing- a list comprehension can do that;

```
files_to_check = [name for name in sorted(os.listdir("/Users/...")) if name.startswith("file")]
```

which gives you every filename, in order, as long as the name begins with `"file"`. You could make it force proper everything, but then you get into regular expressions which are probably overkill in this context.

Comment: You could extend this to handle multiple files in one go (if you're doing this manually, is there really no situation where you would forget/be unable to run it?) by keeping a "posted.txt" file and appending each file name to it after posting.  Then use `os.listdir(path)` in your program as suggested, and compare the results to the results in "posted.txt", and post all the ones with no matches.

Comment: @Delioth       Thank you! Worked great.